# getting 403 in Ant media rest api

Tags: node.js, rest, api, ant-media-server-sdk

I've tried to call api with postman and put IP filter already. I can access ANT api from postman with path parameters. But I can not access api exactly like in the Ant rest documentation.

For instance getting broadcast item in Ant api document,
/v2/broadcasts/{id}

What I can work in postman,
/rest/request?_path=WebRTCAppEE/rest/v2/broadcasts/{id}

I call this post method  to authenticate first with my email and password in postman.
http://myIp:5080/rest/authenticateUser.
And then I call others api like this after in postman.
http://myIp:5080/rest/request?_path=WebRTCAppEE/rest/v2/broadcasts/623967750864416207633038
It works in postman. But when I tried in my nodejs app, it only works for  authenticateUser. I'm getting 403 for other api. Can someone help me check? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`request?_path` syntax is valid for the Dashboard requests. You should use as below:

```
http://myip:5080/WebRTCAppEE/rest/v2/broadcasts/623967750864416207633038
```

Note: Make sure add your IP address in Application/IP filter Setting

Comment: Thanks for answering @Selim
I updated with your api but I'm still getting 403.
I've already add my IP address in IP filter setting.

Comment: Please make sure to add your IP Address in correct application. IP Filter settings should be as below:
127.0.0.1,11.11.11.11
Note: 11.11.11.11 is your sample IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Selim. Now I got access. Problem is I always tried to add my IP from my Dashboard settings like ant documentation. It only works after I call this api and updated remoteAllowedCIDR IP from it.
POST /rest/changeSettings/WebRTCAppEE